# How can I get the rails titlize method in a ruby script (non-rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to make a simple filter script (for vim) that does the following. Unfortunately, it it doesn't work. See error below.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support'


STDIN.each_line { |line|
  puts line.titleize

}
```

Error

```
undefined method `titleize' for "\n":String (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Are you sure you have active_support installed? I can run your script without the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do the following:

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/all' #http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html
```

Apparently just including active_support doesn't do it...

Answer (score 1):

You must require `ActiveSupport::Inflector`.

```
require 'active_support/inflector'
```

Then just call `#titleize`.